# iphone continuous gps location logging

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps

Is it possible for an iphone app to continually send gps device location updates to a remote server, so the device could be "pin-pointed"?

I understand i can get the gps cords and get the app to continue to get them in the background, but im unsure about being able to send the cords to a webservice when in the background mode or if apple would even allow me.

-trav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the apple documentation, I think this should be possible.
But you will not be able to use real GPS  device. When running in the background you will only receive major location changes. Which are detect when the user travels into a new GSM cell.

Read more on background execution: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4

Comment: hmm, i was thinking that might be the case.  I need to send location change push with accuracy of about 30 - 40 meters.

Comment: the link is broken, can you fix it please :)